# SharePoint Approval Workflow Javascript error

Tags: workflow, javascript, error, 2007

I've been trying to create a simple Approval Workflow in SharePoint (MOSS 2007).

After going through the first screen where I type in the name, Task List, History List, startup params, etc. I go on to the next screen and it comes up blank but for a Javascript Error.

*"Line 31 Char 73 Object expected"*

which would be at the body tag doing the SharePoint Built in javascript like so:

```
<BODY scroll="yes" 
      onload="javascript:if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();HideSiteFeatures();">
```

The URL comes up like so, which looks legit:

`http://(site)/_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx?List={6C6EEAB3-4A19-4F1A-BBCD-B555A4BCF2E5}`

I've tried this page with IE 6,7 and 8 and the error keeps coming up.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, apparently it was a Javascript corrupted by someone in the organization who was feeling brave in customizing the application.master file and I didn't realize it.  Reset back to standard application.master fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

As you have used it with various browsers it probably isn't the famous 'corrupt JavaScript file in the browser  cache' problem.

Are you accessing SharePoint via a proxy server by any chance?